# the $\beta$ and $R^2$ of combination of two simple linear regression

Tags: multiple-regression

I saw many times for the interview questions:

suppose $\beta_i, r_i$ is the beta and R squared of data $(\textbf{y},\textbf{x}_i),\ i = 1,2$ respectively.  Then what's the ranges of  beta $\beta = [\beta_1',\beta_2']$ and R squared $r$ for the two variable linear regression of data $(\textbf{y},[\textbf{x}_1,\textbf{x}_2])?$

I know if $\textbf{y},\textbf{x}_1, \textbf{x}_2$ are all normalized then for the simple linear regression we have
$$\beta_i = r_i = r_{iy},\textrm{ correlation coefficient of }\textbf{y},\textbf{x}_i.$$

And the beta of two regression is:

$$\beta_1' = \dfrac{1}{1-r_{12}}(r_{1y} - r_{12}r_{2y}),\ \beta_2' = \dfrac{1}{1-r_{12}}(r_{2y} - r_{12}r_{1y})$$

Here $r_{12}$ is the correlation coefficient of $\textbf{x}_1,\textbf{x}_2.$

I calculated the
$$r^2 = r_{1y}^2 + r_{2y}^2 + 2r_{12}r_{1y}r_{2y}.$$

So my questions are

1. Is normalization assumption correct?
2. How to calculate R squared of two variables regression?
3. What the relation between R squared and Beta for the multiple variables linear regression (don't consider adjusted R squared here)? Can R squared can still be represented by beta for multiple variables?

When $\textbf{x}_i$ are uncorrelated, the R squared seems the sum of components.